# SQL apply functions to multiple id rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008, and trying to gather individual customer data appearing over multiple rows in my table, an example of my database is as follows:

```
custID | status | type  | value 
-------------------------
1      | 1      | A     | 150
1      | 0      | B     | 100
1      | 0      | A     | 153
1      | 0      | A     | 126
2      | 0      | A     | 152
2      | 0      | B     | 101
2      | 0      | B     | 103
```

For each custID, my task is to find a flag if status=1 for any row, if type=B for any row, and the average of value in all cases where type=B. So my solution should look like:

```
custID | statusFlag | typeFlag  | valueAv 
-------------------------------------------
1      | 1          | 1         | 100
2      | 0          | 1         | 102
```

I can get answers for this using lots of row_number() over (partition by .. ), to create ids, and creating subtables for each column selecting the desired id. My issue is this method is awkward and time consuming, as I have many more columns than shown above to do this over, and many tables to repeat it for. My ideal solution would be to define my own aggregate() function so I could just do:

```
select custID, ag1(statusFlag), ag2(typeFlag)
group by custID
```

but as far as I can tell custom aggregates can't be defined in SQL server. Is there a nicer general approach to this problem, which doesn't require defining lots of id's ?

Comment: From where the `1, 102` come from?

Comment: What is the logic behind the `typeFlag`?  Why do both records in your output have 1 for the `typeFlag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CASE WHEN to evaluate the value and apply the aggregate function accordingly

```
select  custID,
        statusFlag  = max(status),
        typeFlag    = max(case when type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end),
        valueAv     = avg(case when type = 'B' then value end)
from    samples
group by custID
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!